# Why does `kill %jobnumber` not work on stopped jobs?

Tags: kill, background-process

I'm running a few tasks side by side on an Ubuntu 18 LTS system. So I'm switching between these jobs by running:

```
# command &
# fg
# fg -
```

I'm also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sometimes to send a running job to the background.

Say I have 3 jobs in my list:

```
# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 nano /etc/nginx/site-available/blog.conf
[2]   Stopped                 top
[3]-  Stopped                 nano script.sh
```

I can successfully switch between these, but when I run the `kill` command on these, the jobs still show in the list. None gets killed. Why?

```
# kill %1
```

I list again, and the jobs are still there:

```
# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 nano /etc/nginx/site-available/blog.conf
[2]   Stopped                 top
[3]-  Stopped                 nano script.sh
```

PS: I can kill jobs with their process IDs, but why not with `kill %1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could not kill process by its PID, then you could not kill it using its job's identifier.

To kill process using its job's identifier without saving data, closing session operations and so on, use:

```
kill -9 %1
```

`kill` sends signal number 15 (SIGTERM) to process, which could be ignored by process as it is in our case, because of it is stopped and, maybe, rejects to listen SIGTERM in stopped state. But signal number 9 (SIGKILL) is sent by kernel and it does not care if process could hear or not. It just ends it forcefully.

Comment: I don't get it, I'd saved the work in job 1, which was nano editing conf file. and then sent it to bg by presseing `ctrl + z`. kill command without -9 should work, no?

Answer (score 4):

There is couple of things to point out here:

1. `kill` without any arguments sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the desired process or job identifier.
2. `SIGTERM` can be ignored by the process receiving it.
3. A process which has been stopped (revived a `SIGSTOP` for example using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) can't do anything (saving a file, etc).

When you run `kill` without an argument on a process which needs specefic steps to get closed but cant (because it's stopped) it does not response to the `SIGTERM` and ignores it. at the other hand `SIGKILL` can not be ignored so it kills the process. that's why a command like `sleep` can be terminated with `kill %1` just fine but a program like `nano` can not.